# Amazon web services elastic beanstalk (Tomcat server)

Tags: apache, jsp, amazon-web-services, servlets, war

I am currently using  elastic beanstalk to run .war file on web server , But the problem is that when ever I need to change some code then I need to upload the entire project again and deploy it ,it's little bit lengthy process and server remain down for few moment , So is there any solution where I can update the project files or add some extra page without letting the server down ?

Answer (score 0):

You set up a blue green deployment with Elastic Beanstalk

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html

Comment: no other option  ? As per your solution I have to upload the entire project again in another aws elastic beanstalk then I can able to swipe and for little modification I need to upload the new war file again ?

Comment: It's the same Elasticbeanstalk application just a second environment. Each environment can have different application versions deployed to it. So when you run a change, you would deploy the new version to the new environment, test, and the swap urls.

Comment: is there any github solution ? Like I upload my project on github and it will update my project on each commit !

Comment: You could use code pipeline to do that with code deploy.

Comment: Great ! I will definitely try your solution , Thanks for fast and helpful replies